# Symfony authentication providers

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, ldap

I'm using `fr3d/ldap-bundle`. It logs me in and imports users from AD if they're not in db. That's fine.

Despite AD users I also have local users, which are in my db. There is special column `authType` which says how user should be authenticated - via LDAP or natively ( FOS ). I've created my own user provider:

```
public function chooseProviderForUsername($username)
{
    if($user->getAuthType() == User::LOGIN_LDAP) {
         $this->properProvider = $this->ldapUserProvider;
     } elseif($user->getAuthType() == User::LOGIN_NATIVE) {
         $this->properProvider = $this->fosUserProvider;
     } else {
         throw new InvalidArgumentException('Error');
     }
}

public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    return $this->chooseProviderForUsername($username)->loadUserByUsername($username);
}
```

**PROBLEM:** Chain provider isn't an option - it allows user to login with his LDAP password AND with his local password! That's a big security issue.

Is there a way to login user via different authentication providers, depending on the db field?

EDIT:

My security.yml:

```
 providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
        appbundle_user_provider:
            id: appbundle.user_provider
        fr3d_ldapbundle:
            id: fr3d_ldap.security.user.provider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        admin:
            pattern: ^/admin.*
            context: user
            fr3d_ldap:  ~
            form_login:
                provider: appbundle_user_provider
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: admin_main
                login_path: /admin/login
                check_path: /admin/login_check
            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /admin/login
            anonymous:    true
```

Here is security.yml. This line `fr3d_ldap:  ~` enables the ldap bundle, which authorize ldap users and saves them into my db. Without it I cannot authorize them,  probably I would have to write custom AuthenticationProvider.

Comment: can you explain "Chain provider" ?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/multiple_user_providers.html

Comment: Could we see your security.yml document where it specifies the providers?

Comment: check now - I've added it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with ldap but I would suggest try doing a completely manual login

```
  $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, "firewallname", $user->getRoles());
  $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
  $securityContext->setToken($token);
```

Then you can manually do the checks yourself, and depending on the result of the check decide how you want to verify the user before authenticating. For example, run a query by username and password before executing this login code or whatever, depending on the db field you want.

Comment: yeah but the problem is what when user is not in db? Then it should be taken from ldap provider ( as it does now ), store it in db ( as it does now ) and authorize him ( as - well, - it does now ).

Comment: build a user entity from the ldap information and authenticate that user. I think that should work. I think whether or not to store that user entity later is optional.

Comment: Well I don't think it is optional. At least I can't find any option whether to save entity or not. And user entity is being built by the bundle I'm currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems fine but you should check logic of your methods.
First of all this one:

```
public function chooseProviderForUsername($username)
{
    if($user->getAuthType() == User::LOGIN_LDAP) {
         $this->properProvider = $this->ldapUserProvider;
     } elseif($user->getAuthType() == User::LOGIN_NATIVE) {
         $this->properProvider = $this->fosUserProvider;
     } else {
         throw new InvalidArgumentException('Error');
     }
}
```

You pass `$username` to this method as an argument, but then use `$user` object, which seems to be undefined in current context.
Secondly:

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    return $this->chooseProviderForUsername($username)->loadUserByUsername($username);
}
```

So as `chooseProviderForUsername` method actually does not return any value you are not able to chain it this way.

I hope refactoring these issues should make your provider work properly.

Comment: ahh, damn, it was just a summary of my code, it doesn't cover all of it. It takes user and than operates on it. The problem is that it always uses both providers..

Comment: When you say it takes user, how does it manipulate it? Does the method take the username then use it to lookup a user object? If so, how does it do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so very brief answer, but I think at the moment Symfony is searching for the user amongst any old User Provider rather than the one you want it to for that particular user (which explains the whole logging in with two passwords thing). A solution should be to make `AppBundleUserProvider` implement `UserProviderInterface`, remove the other User Providers from `security.yml` and then to ensure that the first thing `AppBundleUserProvider` does it to find out which User Provider is required for that user then mimic it for every method in the `UserProviderInterface`. You could set `$this->realUP` based on Username, then set every method to just return `$this->realUP->someMethod()`.

Comment: yeah, that's one solution to the problem, which You can see I've already tried... I am  using appbundle_user_provider. It doesn't implement UserProviderInterface though, but I don't think that changes much.

Comment: Have you tried chain routing with this provider first then the ldap one? At the moment symfony is just using any user provider which returns a user object matching the provided credentials.

Comment: yeah I did, and it creates the problem with logging in with two passwords - if first provider doesn't authenticate, then second one does.

Comment: Hmm, that is a head teaser. I've done something similar to this in the past, would you be happy to post or send me the entire app bundle user provider to look at in the morning?

Comment: user provider only finds users, that is not much. Ldap user provider, if it finds user on ldap server, it creates user entity in local db and saves it. FOS just check in local db. And I just want LDAP to check this authType field and based on that authorize user or not.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I can think of is to create your own [ChainProvider class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/ChainUserProvider.php)  that only allows login with one provider and [use the Dependency Injection Container to use yours](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security.xml#L20).

You just need to override the *security.user.provider.chain.clas* parameter definition in your bundle's config file.

Comment: I've done something similar, but in the end `fr3d_ldap:  ~` in firewall is making security to check ldap server no matter what my provider is. And without this line I can't fully authenticate user that is created "on the fly". I'll have to check @Joe Yahchouchi answer.